# ¿Es posible utilizar la etiqueta <a href=> para mostrar un archivo(.pdf) que se encuentra en una carpeta en el lado del servidor (.aspx.vb)?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy en el ambiente de desarrollo y estoy utilizando la etiqueta =>

`<a href="evidencias/test.pdf">Clic aquí para descargar</a>`; para mostrar una ruta con el archivo que se encuentra en la estructura del proyecto en el lado del servidor. **Mi duda es** si esta forma de descargar el documento; funcionará en producción; pues ahí ya no van a tener la estructura del proyecto de manera local como lo tengo ahora.

[image: Estructura de proyecto en Visual Studio]

**Gracias por sus apoyo.**

Answer (score 1):

si por supuesto:
youHref deberia ser la ruta del documento y esto "target="_blank" rel="noopener"" para que se abra en otra pestana

```
<Link href={youHref} target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      Download Label
</Link>
```

Comment: En realidad para que se abra en una nueva pestaña se requiere solo el `target="_blank"`, `noopener` [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener tiene otra intención de uso no?